# sub command in unix to substitute multiple symbols, how?

Tags: linux, unix, sed

I am using below command for comparing two files with 3rd column having abc.txt and another +abc.txt. It is giving me the proper output by ignoring plus(+) symbol.

How do i add multiple symbols in my code so that it also ignore Plus(+) ymbol as well as exclamation(!) symbol.

Third Column may be having

```
+abc.txt
!abc.txt   --> So It have to ignore + and ! symbol while comparing with abc.txt


FNR==0 {next}
NR==FNR {a[$1]=$0; next} {k=$3; sub(/^\+/,"",k)} k in a {split(a[k], b)
print $1,$2,b[2],$3,b[3],b[4],b[5],$4,$5,$6,$7; delete a[k] }
END {for(k in a) print a[k] > "Compare_unmatched.txt"}
```

Trail:

{k=$3; sub(/^+/,"",k);sub(/^!/,"",k)} - Used this line but it is not giving me proper result.

Could you please suggest me the work around. Thanks!

Comment: Are you comparing the field 3 in the second file with the first fields in the first file? Please add sample in- and output (perhaps after making your question simplier).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `sub("^[+!]", "", k)`. Not sure about the remainder of the code.

Comment: It works fine for me. Thank you sir for your help :)